# GoogleMap V2 doesn't start with user current location

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps, location

I am newbie on Android. I want to develop a simple GoogleMap application. But my app doesn't start with user current location my user current location object is null on application start, when i press the menu key and rerun my app, it shows but i want to show current location when the application start.

Thanks.

This is my Map Fragment.

```
public class HaritaFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener {

private static GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
public static HashMap<Marker, Markers> mMarkersHashMap = new HashMap<Marker, Markers>();
private ArrayList<Markers> mMyMarkersArray = new ArrayList<Markers>();
private Map<Marker, Markers> allMarkersMap = new HashMap<Marker, Markers>();

private Location location;
private Location defaultLocation;

private LatLng latLng;
private Double lat;
private Double lng;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_harita, container, false);
}

public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    googleAnalyticsSendScreen();

    // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity().getBaseContext());

    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, getActivity(), requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    } else { // Google Play Services are available


        mGoogleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Boolean isGPSProviderEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Boolean isNetworkProviderEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


        //TOOLBARS Disabled.
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);


        if (isNetworkProviderEnabled){
            location =  locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            defaultLocation = mGoogleMap.getMyLocation();}

        if (isGPSProviderEnabled){
            location =  locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            defaultLocation = mGoogleMap.getMyLocation();}
        else {

            if (mMyMarkersArray.isEmpty()){

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle(R.string.location_error_title);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.location_error_message);
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();}
        }

        if (defaultLocation != null) {
            onLocationChanged(defaultLocation);
            latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));

        }
        //Location yoksa default value ve zoom value ile yaratıyor.
else if (defaultLocation != null){
    onLocationChanged(defaultLocation);

    latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));}

        else{

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Still NULL",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            latLng = new LatLng(41.048846, 29.027924);
            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 11));
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    googleAnalyticsSendScreen();

    // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity().getBaseContext());

    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, getActivity(), requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    } else { // Google Play Services are available

        getAllDataFromParse();
        setUpMap();


    }
}

private void getAllDataFromParse(){

    if (mMyMarkersArray.isEmpty()){

        if (isInternetAvailable()){
            unPinMemberNO();
            getOnlineDataFromParse();
        }

        else{
            getOfflineDataFromParse();
        }
    }
}

private void unPinMemberNO(){

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Veterinerler");
    query.setLimit(1000);
    query.whereEqualTo("isMember", "NO");
    ParseObject.unpinAllInBackground();
}

private void getOnlineDataFromParse(){

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Veterinerler");
    query.setLimit(1000);
    query.whereEqualTo("isMember", "YES");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        public void done(List<ParseObject> vetList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                for(int i=0; i< vetList.size(); i++){

                    mMyMarkersArray.add(new Markers(

                            vetList.get(i).getString("adi"),
                            vetList.get(i).getString("adres"),
                            vetList.get(i).getString("telefon"),
                            vetList.get(i).getString("web"),
                            vetList.get(i).getString("face"),
                            vetList.get(i).getString("geceAcik"),
                            vetList.get(i).getDouble("latitude"),
                            vetList.get(i).getDouble("longitude")));
                }

                plotMarkers(mMyMarkersArray);
                ParseObject.pinAllInBackground(vetList);

            } else {

            }
        }
    });
}

private void getOfflineDataFromParse(){

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Veterinerler");
    query.setLimit(1000);
    query.whereEqualTo("isMember", "YES");
    query.fromLocalDatastore();
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        public void done(List<ParseObject> vetList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                for(int i=0; i< vetList.size(); i++){

                    mMyMarkersArray.add(new Markers(

                            vetList.get(i).getString("adi"),
                            vetList.get(i).getString("adres"),
                            vetList.get(i).getString("telefon"),
                            vetList.get(i).getString("web"),
                            vetList.get(i).getString("face"),
                            vetList.get(i).getString("geceAcik"),
                            vetList.get(i).getDouble("latitude"),
                            vetList.get(i).getDouble("longitude")));
                }

                plotMarkers(mMyMarkersArray);

            } else {

            }
        }
    });
}


private void googleAnalyticsSendScreen() {

    Tracker t = ((GlobalState) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
            GlobalState.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    t.setScreenName("Harita Ekranı");
    t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
}

private void plotMarkers(ArrayList<Markers> markers)
{
    if(markers.size() > 0)
    {
        for (Markers myMarker : markers)
        {
            // Create user marker with custom icon and other options
            MarkerOptions markerOption = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(myMarker.getmLatitude(), myMarker.getmLongtitude()));

            if (myMarker.getmGeceAcik().equalsIgnoreCase("YES")){

                markerOption.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            }

            else if (myMarker.getmGeceAcik().equalsIgnoreCase("Cep")){

                markerOption.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            }

            else if (myMarker.getmGeceAcik().equalsIgnoreCase("Barinak")){

                markerOption.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET));
            }


            final Marker currentMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOption);
            mMarkersHashMap.put(currentMarker, myMarker);
            allMarkersMap.put(currentMarker, myMarker);

            mGoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

                    Markers selectedMarkerInfo = allMarkersMap.get(marker);

                    View v = View.inflate(getActivity().getBaseContext(),R.layout.info_window,null);

                    TextView tvAdi = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_adi);
                    TextView tvAdres = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_adres);
                    ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_icon);

                    tvAdi.setText(selectedMarkerInfo.getmAdi());
                    tvAdres.setText(selectedMarkerInfo.getmAdres());
                    tvAdi.setSelected(true);

                    if (selectedMarkerInfo.mGeceAcik.equalsIgnoreCase("Barinak")){

                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.belediye);
                    }

                    else if (selectedMarkerInfo.mGeceAcik.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")){

                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.gece_acik);
                    }

                    else if (selectedMarkerInfo.mGeceAcik.equalsIgnoreCase("Cep")){

                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.acil);
                    }

                    else{

                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.normal);
                    }
                    return v;
                }

                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                    return null;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

private void  setUpMap(){



            //OnClick Info Window Listener...
            mGoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                    Markers selectedMarkerInfo = allMarkersMap.get(marker);

                    //GOOGLE ANALYTICS EVENT SENDER
                    String secilenVeteriner = selectedMarkerInfo.getmAdi();
                    Tracker t = ((GlobalState) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
                            GlobalState.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

                    t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                            .setCategory(secilenVeteriner)
                            .setAction("Harita ekranın'dan seçilme sayınız")
                            .setLabel("Harita")
                            .build());

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra("adi", selectedMarkerInfo.getmAdi());
                    intent.putExtra("adres", selectedMarkerInfo.getmAdres());
                    intent.putExtra("web", selectedMarkerInfo.getmWeb());
                    intent.putExtra("face", selectedMarkerInfo.getmFace());
                    intent.putExtra("tel", selectedMarkerInfo.getmTelefon());
                    intent.putExtra("lat", selectedMarkerInfo.getmLatitude().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("lng", selectedMarkerInfo.getmLongtitude().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("gece", selectedMarkerInfo.getmGeceAcik());

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

}

private boolean isInternetAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lat =  (location.getLatitude());
        lng =  (location.getLongitude());
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_mail) {

        Instabug.getInstance().setCommentFieldHint(getString(R.string.veterinerbildir_comment));
        Instabug.getInstance().enableEmailField(true,true);
        Instabug.getInstance().setCommentRequired(true);

        Instabug.getInstance().invokeFeedbackProcess(Instabug.INSTABUG_FEEDBACK_FEEDBACK);

        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.map_standart){

        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    }

    if (id == R.id.map_hibrit){

        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    }

    if (id == R.id.map_uydu){

        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

There is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends InstabugActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;
FragmentManager manager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.nav_logo);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        //.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setIcon(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getIcon(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_mail) {

        Instabug.getInstance().setCommentFieldHint(getString(R.string.veterinerbildir_comment));
        Instabug.getInstance().enableEmailField(true,true);
        Instabug.getInstance().setCommentRequired(true);

        Instabug.getInstance().invokeFeedbackProcess(Instabug.INSTABUG_FEEDBACK_FEEDBACK);

        return true;
    }

    else if (id == R.id.action_about){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,InfoActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());


}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}
```

There is my Fragment_Activitiy XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity$HaritaFragment">


<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

And the Manifest XML

```
<!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

There is the LogCat output

```
02-28 12:30:48.118  29049-29129/com.esmobileinc.vetmapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.esmobileinc.vetmapp.h.a(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.b(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.v.a(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.v.a(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.e.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.v.e(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.v.b(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.app.aa.b(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.a(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.c(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4706)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2163)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:13011)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1084)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2498)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What is the problem ? I just want start my app with user location.

Thanks !

I did this, like you said but still same doesn't start with user location.

Comment: because you are creating id in on resume. use in on create view. see fragment life cycle..

Comment: I agree with @Shadow

Comment: What is the id ? Which code should I use on create view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should move all your code inside `onResume()` to `onViewCreated()`, which is the correct place in a `Fragment` to perform all such setups.

**EDIT:**

You have moved the code to `onCreateView()` which is not the same as `onViewCreated()`. Plus, the order of map initialization is not right.

Your `onCreateView()` should look like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_harita, container, false);
}
```

and your map initialization should be done in `onViewCreated()` like this:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    googleAnalyticsSendScreen();

    // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity().getBaseContext());

    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, getActivity(), requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    } else { // Google Play Services are available

        getAllDataFromParse();
        setUpMap();

        mGoogleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Boolean isGPSProviderEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Boolean isNetworkProviderEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


        //TOOLBARS Disabled.
        mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);


        if (isNetworkProviderEnabled){
            location =  locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            defaultLocation = mGoogleMap.getMyLocation();}

            if (isGPSProviderEnabled){
                location =  locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        defaultLocation = mGoogleMap.getMyLocation();}
           else {

                if (mMyMarkersArray.isEmpty()){

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle(R.string.location_error_title);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.location_error_message);
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();}
          }

          if (defaultLocation != null) {
              onLocationChanged(defaultLocation);
              latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
              mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));

    }
   //Location yoksa default value ve zoom value ile yaratıyor.
   /* else if (defaultLocation != null){
        onLocationChanged(defaultLocation);

        latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));}*/

            else{
                latLng = new LatLng(41.048846, 29.027924);
                mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 11));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: when i move all codes to onViewCreated() application crash with ﹕ dbclose(): path = /data/data/com.esmobileinc.vetmapp/databases/instabugdb, handle = 0x1307c90
02-28 12:26:19.236  27942-28045/com.esmobileinc.vetmapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.esmobileinc.vetmapp.h.a(Unknown Source)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.b(Unknown Source)

Comment: post all your Fragment code in the question along with logcat of error

Comment: i tried your codes error is gone but still doesn't start with user location. our defaultLocation object is still NULL. Please see my edited question Fragment codes, i updated with my last tried codes and Thanks for helping to me !

Comment: @emresancaktar: will take a look at this in a while

Comment: @emresancaktar: where have you reached so far ?

Comment: I solve the problem, actually its not a right solution but its ok for now. I moved the setupMap method inside the getAllDataFromParse Async method and its working now. When the async task is complete camera animates to the user current location. Thank you for your helps.